# pipe one file at a time python

Tags: python, iteration

I have more than 10000 json files which I have to convert to for further processing.  I am using the following code:

```
import json
import time
import os
import csv
import fnmatch

tweets = []
count = 0

search_folder = ('/Volumes/Transcend/Axiom/IPL/test/')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_folder):
    for file in files:
        pathname = os.path.join(root, file)

for file in open(pathname):
    try:
        tweets.append(json.loads(file))
    except:
        pass

count = count + 1
```

This iterates over just one file and stops.  I tried adding `while True:` before `for file in open(pathname):` and it just doesn't stop nor it creates the csv files.  I want to read one file at a time, convert it to csv, then move on to the next file.  I tried adding `count = count + 1` at the end of the file after completing converting the csv.  Still it stops after converting the first file.  Can someone help please?

Comment: the first loop finds all the files. then it ends. the second `for` loop opens the _last_ file found and reads the lines in it. you need to indent the second for loop so that it is operating on each file found. plus other tweaks.

Comment: are all the files in one folder or actually in subdirectories?

Comment: Also do all the files end in .json?

Comment: Yes....all the files are in the same folder and ends with .json.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off; you need to put the second `for` loop inside the first one.

Separate from your main problem, you should use a `with` statement to open the file. Also, you were reusing the variable name `file`, which you shouldn't be using anyway since it's the name of a built-in. I also made a few other minor edits.

```
import json
import os

tweets = []
count = 0

search_folder = '/Volumes/Transcend/Axiom/IPL/test/'

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(search_folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        pathname = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(pathname, 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                try:
                    tweets.append(json.loads(line))
                except:  # Don't use bare except clauses
                    pass

        count += 1
```

Comment: many thanks for the suggestions and corrections.  I implemented the code.  Just to test, I moved couple of files to a test folder and ran the code.  The loop iterates over the same file twice,  and it runs extremely slow....as in...if i do the data extraction manually it would be over in 15 - 16 seconds for a file whereas now it takes more than 6 mins.....could you please advice?  Thank you again..